# Best cipher/encryption suggestions for JWT tokens

Tags: ssl, jwt

I've been running some load tests on our servers recently and noticed that our JWT token serialization/deserialization seems to be quite a bottleneck. This is likely due to the fact that we're using a 2048 self-signed key. I was wondering what cipher and encryption size would be acceptable security-wise but also decrease load?

All transactions against our API are already SSL'd so I'm making a basic assumption that a weaker key wouldn't be problematic. Also we're expiring tokens frequently.

Suggests would be most appreciated.

Comment: security.stackexchange.com is probably a better site to ask this. Apart from that SSL only protects against sniffing or modification during transport which is only one of several attack vectors.

Comment: Ah, thanks and good point =)

Comment: I guess you are using an asymmetric RSA keypair. RSA signature is slower than HMAC. If you do not need that your clients verify the token( probably it can be ommited because you are using SSL and the client is already checking the server certificate), to increase performance you can replace RSA with HMAC without affecting security. Note that JWT is.signed, not encrypted

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @pedrofb, you should submit this as an answer though. If someone retrieves the JWT token, can they deserialize it at all? We're retaining some information in there, which isn't sensitive but we still want it locked down.

Comment: Yes, the content is only base64 encoded, but you could apply JWE encryption. See answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an asymmetric RSA keypair. RSA signature is slower than HMAC. If you do not need that your clients verify the token( probably it can be ommited because you are using SSL and the client is already checking the server certificate), **to increase performance you can replace RSA with HMAC without affecting security**.

---

Note that JWT is generally signed, not encrypted. The payload is base64 encoded so anyone with a JWT can read its contents.

The signature ensures the identity of the issuer and protects the token against alterations. If you want to hide the content is possible to apply JWE encryption to JWT, but then you'll get less performance. Check if your library supports it.

Comment: indeed the RSA signature is performance expensive, though if it is really needed, we advice to cache the jwt token for its validity lifespan. if the data are encrypted, then you cannot do much about it, the performance is price for the security. the question is, if you need to encrypt the whole message, if TLS/SSL is enough

Comment: Hmac is much faster than RSA, but adding encryption will increase generation and decryption operations, as you said. I do not think JWT caching is a good idea because it loses its advantages: statelessness and no need of  server storage. If the performance is the bottleneck and some content must be hidden, then this attributes could not be included at all in the JWT or even use opaque tokens with a server session